# Can sentences be joined when we need to say "such as X OR Y"?

Tags: sentence-construction, conjunctions, clauses, logic, run-on-sentences

When defining something, it can also be defined, for example, as A or B. If I give you a practical case to this situation,

> 1. The idea behind the process is to find a common envelope.
> 2. The envelope should be going through the longest line’s outer end.
>      or
> 3. the envelope should accommodate all the lines’ outer ends on to that.

then, how can the above be defined by a single sentence? Can anyone suggest a way to join all three sentences into one?

Comment: The idea ... find a common envelope which should ... or should ... - Or what are you asking about?

Comment: @Em1: I want to join all 3 sentences into one in such a way to saying that 1 can be define with 2 or 3.

Comment: This question is quite localised, i.e. narrow in scope. Is it possible you could reword it in a way that makes it applicable to more people?

Comment: @Matt Ellen: I guess, I did it now as it might be more general.

Comment: The question is, perhaps, made more difficult to answer because the example is unclear. How does an envelope go through a line? Are you talking about a paper envelope that one would use to mail a letter, or something else? What is the "line" that you are referring to? This is all tangential to the actual question, but you may need to reword these sentences to make sense to the reader.

Comment: @Jay I think by "envelope" OP means a smooth closed curve, and by "outer ends" endpoints. Although I can't be sure.

Comment: @SenjougaharaHitagi I'm not sure if the question has been edited since my post or if I was just dense. Yes, by "envelope" he presumably means a geometric figure that has some relation to the set of line segments that he describes, presumably surrounding or enclosing these line segments in some way. But beyond that I'm still not clear what he's driving at. I think this is more a geometry question than an English question.

Answer (score 5):

1. Identify unnecessary or vague ‘filler’ words.

   > Are you defining *the idea behind the process*? —It appears that what you are really doing is describing what the process does.
   >   What does *common* mean here? Common to what? —it appears to mean that it includes the outer ends of all the lines.
2. Pin down what's left that needs to be defined in detail.

   > In this case, that would appear to be *envelope*. Define *envelope*, or recall the definition if you have defined it previously. If the *envelope* has specific local qualities, include those: ‘the most efficient envelope’ or ‘smallest’ or whatever it is that is actually found.
3. Rewrite without the filler words and incorporating the definition.

   > The process finds the *envelope*—the [?smallest?] closed curve which either passes through or encloses the outer endpoints of all the lines.

Answer (score 4):

Since your condition matching is `either...or` case, the given three sentences can be merged as follows:

> The idea behind the process is to find a common envelope which should
>   **either** be going through the longest line's outer end **or** accommodate
>   all the lines' outer ends on to that.